OpenCL kernel sets an improper value to a matrix after convolution of a 2d cnn
I am writing a software for convolution of 2D images. I am adopting OpenCL due to the high performance on big images (30 MB and above). I have the following kernel code:
static const char* src3x3= R"(
    __kernel void conv3x3(__global unsigned int *pixels, unsigned int gwidth, unsigned int gheight,
    __global float* kern)
    {
        unsigned int MyMat[9];
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        int y = get_global_id(1);

        int res = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <3; i++) {
            int r,g,b;
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                r = (pixels[(x+j) + (gwidth * (y+i))] >> 16) & 0xFFu;
                g = (pixels[(x+j) + (gwidth * (y+i))] >> 8) & 0xFFu;
                b = (pixels[(x+j) + (gwidth * (y+i))]) & 0xFFu;
                r *= kern[i * 3 + j];
                g *= kern[i * 3 + j];
                b *= kern[i * 3 + j];
                MyMat[i * 3 + j]= (0xFF000000) | ( ( r & 0xFFu) << 16) | ( (g & 0xFFu) << 8)  | (b & 0xFFu);
           }
        }
        pixels[y * gwidth + x] = MyMat[4];

    }
)";

and the following [host]:
void gpu_kernel::conv3x3(unsigned int *pixels, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h,
                         float (&kern)[9])
{
    size_t dim = 2;
    size_t global_offset[] = {x, y};
    size_t global_size[] = {w, h};
    size_t wsize = 0 ;
    size_t globwsize = w * h * sizeof(unsigned int);
    cl_mem bufferx,  bufferkern;
    size_t log_size;
    char* program_log = 0;
    printf("x:%lu y:%lu w:%lu h:%lu size is (%lu)\r\n", x, y, w, h,globwsize);
    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &m_kernctx.platform, &m_kernctx.platforms);
    clGetDeviceIDs(m_kernctx.platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &m_kernctx.device, &m_kernctx.numdevs);
    m_kernctx.context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &m_kernctx.device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m_kernctx.command_queue =     clCreateCommandQueue(m_kernctx.context, m_kernctx.device, 0, NULL);
    bufferx =   clCreateBuffer(m_kernctx.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                             globwsize , pixels, NULL);

    bufferkern = clCreateBuffer(m_kernctx.context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                                sizeof(float) * 9 , kern , NULL);

    m_kernctx.program = clCreateProgramWithSource(m_kernctx.context, 1, &src3x3, NULL, &m_kernctx.compilerr);
    if (m_kernctx.compilerr) {
        return;
    }

    cl_int res = clBuildProgram(m_kernctx.program, 1, &m_kernctx.device, "", NULL, NULL);
    if (res < 0) {
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(m_kernctx.program, m_kernctx.device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                              0, NULL, &log_size);
        program_log = (char*) calloc(log_size+1, sizeof(char));
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(m_kernctx.program, m_kernctx.device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                              log_size+1, program_log, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", program_log);
        free(program_log);
        return;
    }
    cl_int callres = 0;
    m_kernctx.kernel = clCreateKernel(m_kernctx.program, "conv3x3", NULL);
    callres |= clSetKernelArg(m_kernctx.kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferx);
    callres |= clSetKernelArg(m_kernctx.kernel, 1, sizeof(unsigned int), &w);
    callres |= clSetKernelArg(m_kernctx.kernel, 2, sizeof(unsigned int), &h);
    callres |= clSetKernelArg(m_kernctx.kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferkern);

    callres |= clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(m_kernctx.kernel, m_kernctx.device,  CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &wsize, NULL);
    callres |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(m_kernctx.command_queue,
                                      m_kernctx.kernel,
                                      dim,
                                      global_offset,
                                      global_size,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL);

    clFlush(m_kernctx.command_queue);
    clFinish(m_kernctx.command_queue);

    callres|= clEnqueueReadBuffer(m_kernctx.command_queue, bufferx, CL_TRUE, 0,  globwsize, pixels, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clReleaseMemObject(bufferx);
    clReleaseMemObject(bufferkern);
}

The problem is in the kernel assigning the new middle element to the original data :
        pixels[y * gwidth + x] = MyMat[4];

if however changed to :
        pixels[y * gwidth + x] ^= MyMat[4];

it does change the image across however not with the bulr filter that is :
[0.111,0.111,0.111,
0.111,0.111,0.111,
0.111,0.111,0.111];

Below are some examples of the application:
The original image:

Without opencl blurring:

Assigning with  pixels[y * gwidth + x] = MyMat[4];

Substracting (to test) the original by mid pixels[y * gwidth + x] -= MyMat[4];

I am using AMD RYZEN PRO7 Series with GPU (however can't recall the model) on Ubuntu 22.04 with installed AMD driver from the official site https://support.zivid.com/en/latest/getting-started/software-installation/gpu/install-opencl-drivers-ubuntu.html
I've tested different modifications and the only one that seems not to work is the one that I need to set the middle element to the output data. I've searched for similar problems but I couldn't find any.
Any advice would be helpful. I am new to OpenCL so I may also have misused it or did something incorrect.
[EDIT] I've changed my convolutional kernel to:
    __kernel void conv3x3(__global unsigned int *pixels, unsigned int w, unsigned int h,
    __global float* kern)
    {
        unsigned int MyMat[9];
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        int y = get_global_id(1);
        for(int i=0; i <3; i++) {
            int resr = 0, resg=0, resb=0;
            int r,g,b;
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                r = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 16) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                g = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 8) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                b = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 0) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                resr += r;
                resg += g;
                resb += b;
                MyMat[i * 3 + j] = (0xFF000000) | (resr & 0xFFu) << 16 | (resg & 0xFFu) << 8 | (resb & 0xFFu);
            }
        }
        pixels[y * w + x] = MyMat[4];
    }


then I've applied the identity kernel filter:
[0,0,0,
0,1,0,
0,0,0]

And I got a non modified image assuming the opencl works as expected, however I got some error on cumulative convolutions, and still blur does not work makes the image too dark, but assuming the identity does not change the color it means the pipeline is at least ok.
Here is how it looks on cumulative convolutions with identity kernel and the error. Guess I will investigate for bugs and for now I think there is no problem in opencl. Will close it. Thanks to everyone who gave some suggestions.


Why use %lu and not %u to print an unsigned?  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Since I used size_t originally, I've removed all the prints and error checks, there are none I've even added printf to the kernel to see the value of the kernel and it's not 0s or only 1s.

Why is this question tagged tensorflow? Seems completely unrelated to tensorflow.

sorry it was suggested by SO

What I often do to debug OpenCL programs is create a version which runs the kernel as a c function on the host. For debugging, the performance doesn't matter. I suggest you try that. Also, check all the return codes from the API calls. Do other OpenCL programs run okay on your build? e.g. clinfo Your GPU model matters. If it's an old one like RX580, OpenCL probably won't work.

yes, I've checked all return codes, just removed them from the snippet to avoid more code. I will try to move it entirely in the original host program avoiding opencl host/kernel to see if it will convolve , answering your question for errors, I don't have any.

You also selected DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, so if your CPU supports OpenCL, which it probably does, then it may be included if the proper drivers are installed, then you have to select the device you want from a list. Also if your CPU has integrated graphics, there may be 3 possible devices. Managing the Platforms/Devices part of OpenCL isn't fun and often code just assumes there's just one of each and won't work otherwise. If you've just copied and pasted this from somewhere, you probably need to look again at that.

I am learning some basics from Open CL in Action book, and originally the code didn't work before I install the AMD drivers (I've posted above), but the tech to use a specific device totally run past me. Otherwise it mutates the image quite fast on cold cache then it speeds up but with a non desired result.

Did you read the warning about the AMD OpenCL drivers? What is the model of your GPU? Use sudo lshw and search for display. As far as I know, the only reliable way to run OpenCL on AMD GPUs is with their ROCm driver, which is a bit of a faff to install. Also, the last time I looked, only RX5000 series and later are supported.

It looks like:
product: Cezanne
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: d1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz

Also after installing the driver from my post I got the vendors in etc:
/etc/OpenCL/vendors$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15 юли 30 14:29 amdocl64_50203.icd
Before that the program just crashes so it's a must.

It looks like it's Vega then. ROCm won't support it unless you can get hold of an old version. I suggest you try running it on your CPU instead with CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU.

Well now nothing happens on the image even if I set the image pixel to some constant value, I will check all return codes back to see how the host is preparing all.

Well, hate to say it, but I think your best options might be to get a RDNA discrete GPU from AMD, or a Nvidia GPU, Pascal or later, or abandon OpenCL.

well apparently I've checked my kernel and edit it a bit, see in EDIT

For anyone interested in the solution, apparently I was able to find how to fix the problem.

It was a logic miss in the kernel. I've refactored it from 2d to 3d (see below):

    __kernel void conv3x3(__global unsigned int *pixels, unsigned int w, unsigned int h,
    __global float* kern)
    {
        unsigned int MyMat[9];
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        int y = get_global_id(1);
        int k = get_global_id(2);
        int resr = 0, resg=0, resb=0;
        int r,g,b;
        unsigned int it=0;
        for(int i=0; i <3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                r = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 16) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                g = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 8) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                b = ((pixels[(x+j) + w * (y+i)] >> 0) & 0xFFu) * kern[i * 3 +j];
                resr += r;
                resg += g;
                resb += b;
            }
        }
        MyMat[k] = (0xFF000000) | (resr & 0xFFu) << 16 | (resg & 0xFFu) << 8 | (resb & 0xFFu);
        resr=resg=resb=r=g=b=0;
        pixels[y * w + x] = MyMat[4];
    }

And the host now uses 3 dimensions (first 2 are for the image x/y) 3rd is used for iterating the 3x3 kernel (only the difference from the OP).
host:
    size_t dim = 3;
    size_t global_offset[] = {x, y,0};
    size_t global_size[] = {w, h,9};


The result is blurry (not perfect but pretty close) and using CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU.
It's much more blurred but I assume that mixing float and ints in OpenCL may result in some artefacts and also I need to revisit or to examine this again as a standalone host program to verify same outputs.

